# In response to api, hieroglyphs come

Tags: php, api

I am making an API to the service in the response, hieroglyphs come, although there is no such thing during tests in postman

```
$client = new Client();
$client->setMethod('PUT');
$client->setUri($uri);
$client->setHeaders($headers);
$client->setRawBody(json_encode($body));
$response = $client->send();
$response = $response->getContent();

$headers = [
  'Authorization' => "************************",
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
];
```

I expect a response in the correct form of json

[image: response]

Comment: What client library are you using? What do the response headers look like? (`Content-Encoding` in particular).

Comment: II'm using the Zend\Http\Client library. No response headers

Comment: When you say "No response headers" do you mean there really aren't any response headers at all … or that you haven't looked / don't know how to look?

Comment: I mean, I didn't make any changes myself. Headlines from the box, now I look and unsubscribe

Comment: "I mean, I didn't make any changes myself" — what matters, first and foremost, is what the server says, not if it says it because of something you've done.

Comment: Thanks, I saw a problem in encoding) content-encoding: gzip

Comment: Try using `getBody()` instead of `getContent()`. Docs seem to indicate that `getBody()` will decode the data according to the encoding header.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by adding 'Accept-Encoding' => 'application/json'

```
$client = new Client();
$client->setMethod('PUT');
$client->setUri($uri);
$client->setHeaders($headers);
$client->setRawBody(json_encode($body));
$response = $client->send();
$response = $response->getContent();

$headers = [
  'Authorization' => "************************",
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  'Accept-Encoding' => 'application/json'
];
```